# Access violation occurs using tbb::allocator<T>.allocate

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, tbb

I am trying to use TBB to boost the performance of a computer vision project which uses OpenCV. Here is the part in the code which gives access violation.

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "tbb/pipeline.h"
#include "tbb/tick_count.h"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
#include "tbb/tbb_allocator.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string file = "myimage.jpg";
    Mat* mats2=tbb::tbb_allocator<Mat>().allocate(100);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
    {
        mats2[i]=imread(file);         <===== Access Violation
        imshow("temp",mats3[i]);
        waitKey(1);
    }
}
```

Why is this an Access Violation? Mats2 is not 0 and is definitely assigned to an address in memory. I know other functions from this [link](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/doxygen/a00426.html) that I can use but I want to know what happens in tbb_allocator that leads to this error. The code doesn't give error if used with malloc or scalable_malloc.

Comment: Consider setting the c++ tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seems, it is a C-C++ issue. New and Delete worked but still scalable allocation gives access violation. Sound like the only option for OpenCV users right now.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if this might help

`imread(filename)`

is just an attempts to infer the format of the file from its content. 
Just check how you are required to use this call .

Comment: I hardly believe that's the case. imread reads an image and stores it in a Mat container. It shouldn't have worked with malloc as well if this was the case.